# Can you work directly with files in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was working a little bit with Digital Ocean where you have your own Linux machine and you can directly work with files in the server. But in Elastic Beanstalk it seems like you have less control over what you can do.
All I can do is upload a zip of my website and upload it? Or I can somehow work against files in the server directly?

Even if I need a small change, I must change it in my development environment and then upload to Beanstalk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Beanstalk you have direct access to your EC2 instances, but you're much better off going through the full build and deployment cycle, otherwise the changes you make on one instance won't be propagated to all your instances, and if your instances are recycled for some reason your changes will be lost.

Comment: Sorry that I'm going to ask a beginners question: Only yesterday I started with AWS, so according to what you say: I can have 2 beanstalk projects (which creates 2 different IPs and EC2 behind them) - but that refer to the same website - in case I need to spread the connection on multiple IPs, and they are all connected, so if I deploy on 1 beanstalk environment, it will update the others?

Comment: Typically, your application on Beanstalk will be behind a load balancer and auto-scaling group so if you start getting lots of traffic, Beanstalk would spin up another instance to help handle the load. If you made changes manually to one instance, it wouldn't be automatically propagated to the other. Then, when the load drops off and your instances scale down, you'd lose your manual changes.

Comment: By manually you mean as I suggested in the post? i.e to try and access the EC2? And by automatically you mean to use the "Upload and Deploy" button? 
Let's say the load balancer splitted it to 2 instances, and I use "Upload and Deploy" on 1 of them - do you consider that as "automatically" making changes? And will that give me some sort of prompt to make changes to all the running instances?

Comment: Yes, by manually, I'd mean SSH'ing into an EC2 instance and making changes directly to files on that server; and automatically would be going through the AWS console and letting Beanstalk handle the upload and deployment.

Comment: Got it, so that's why when creating Beanstalk instance, you don't have an option to create SSH key/pair as you would with EC2, right?
And last thing! currently when I have 1 beanstalk instance, and I deploy my project, it simply uploads it. But I wonder how it actually looks like when u have 2 instances for the same project and you want to make changes to all: Does Amazon detect that they are all connected, and does that for you, or it gives you some sort of message before making changes, or how does that look?

Comment: Or, the load balancer doesn't create a new environment but simply appends the existing environment a new ip which is somewhere in sort of "Sub-ips" section on the console?

Comment: Beanstalk will scale up and scale down the EC2 instances behind the load balancer as required, where each instance is just another copy of your application. Each instance would have a separate IP address, but clients of your application would be connecting to the load balancer rather than to the individual EC2's so what's happening underneath is transparent. Beanstalk will handle the deployment of any changes to all your running instances, letting you configure this in a couple of ways: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.rolling-version-deploy.html